# Why Am I getting this Router Error , Check Description for error (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am following a tutorial on React Router and copied exactly the same thing yet I get this errors in console

Error 1 - index.js:16 Uncaught Error: A  is only ever to be used as the child of  element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your  in a .

Error 2 - react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the  component:

This is my code in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './Components/HomePage/HomePage'
import WhoWeHelp from './Components/WhoWeHelpPage/WhoWeHelp';
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Switch , Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/whowehelp" component={WhoWeHelp} />
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Which react router version are you using? Check the version number in package.json. In case of v6, component & switch keywords have been replaced.

Comment: @umar I am using v6.2.2 , so does that mean I am looking at an outdated tutorial ?

Comment: yes, you are following an outdated tutorial. I would recommend visiting the docs for v6 https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview as many more functions and keywords have been changed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all the `Route` in the `Routes` component. You also need to remove the div as Route needs direct nesting

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

 <Router>
   <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element ={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/whowehelp" element ={<WhoWeHelp />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

---

Updated `component` to `element` as pointed out in the comments. `Component` has been replaced by `element` in react router v6. See the changes [here](https://dev.to/gabrlcj/react-router-v6-some-of-the-new-changes-181m)

Comment: component has been replaced by element in react router v6

Comment: Agreed and updated the answer.

Comment: 1 more thing, the syntax of calling component inside element is different. You have to do like this: element={<HomePage />}

Comment: I am still getting the same errors even after doing what the two of you suggested. Changed component to element and tried both methods and also wrapped them in <Routes> and also imported it but getting same exact errors

Comment: I fixed it by getting rid of the div under <Routes> which has a className of App

Comment: I was about to type the same, but you beat me to it :)